# Combine Commits within TFS

Tags: tfs, version-control

So in Git you can squash multiple commits into a single commit. So for example, let's say I checked in a change, but I realized I forgot something small, so I make the change locally and then I commit again. With Git squash you can merge those into one commit.

My question is does TFS have any sort of method for doing the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. TFVC uses a totally different version control paradigm than Git; it does not support history rewriting actions like squashing and amending.

Answer (score 3):

No, its not supported. You can't change the history of every changest in TFVC. If it can be achieved , it's a violation of the principle of source control.

And also you can't create a new changest then merge with the old changest, There have been a featured request in Uservoice and be declined by PM of TFS.

> [TFS to merge multiple, non-continuous changesets.](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2638075-tfs-to-merge-multiple-non-continuous-changesets)
>
> Thanks for the feedback on this idea. We have reviewed this feedback
>   and determined that we will not be able to complete this suggestion in
>   the foreseeable future.
>
> Matt Mitrik TFS Program Manager

Comment: `it's a violation of the principle of source control.`

This is all good and well if you're sticking to theory of source control, but from a practical standpoint, there are a variety of use-cases where it is advantageous or desired to rewrite history. 

  

For example, sensitive information being committed to a repository is something you'd want to expunge from history.